# Node.js streaming adventure lesson 6: declaring a variable vs. in-line function declaration

Tags: node.js

Learning node.js, with NodeSchool.io and I'm confused as to the differences between the following two code segments.  The difference is probably fundamental to node.js or just js in general, so I'm hoping an expert can clarify this to me.

The accepted answer to lesson 6 is the following.  Notice that through(...) is piped in-line.

```
var http = require('http');
var through = require('through');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        req.pipe(through(function (buf) {
            this.queue(buf.toString().toUpperCase());
        })).pipe(res);
    }
    else res.end('send me a POST\n');
});
server.listen(parseInt(process.argv[2]));
```

My solution (which fails) was to declare a variable `tr` like so:

```
var http = require('http');
var through = require('through');

var tr = through(function(buf) {
    this.queue(buf.toString().toUpperCase());
});

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        req.pipe(tr).pipe(res);
    }
    else res.end();
}).listen(process.argv[2]);
```

Why do these two code blocks produce different results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental difference between your version of the code and the version suggested as the right solution is that in your version you create your through stream only once, which means that it works the first time you call it, and by the second time you do a request, your stream is already exhausted (i.e. it has already reached an end from the previous invocation) and so it blocks since it will never reach an end again.

Thus, you need a new through stream every time. For instance, you would not have had that problem, if you had written it this way:

```
var http = require('http');
var through = require('through');

var tr = function(){
    return through(function(buf) {
        this.queue(buf.toString().toUpperCase());
    });
};

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        req.pipe(tr()).pipe(res);
    }
    else res.end();
}).listen(process.argv[2]);
```

Comment: upvote for showing how I would adapt my version to work with the solution.  sigh... I'm finding this a significant learning curve.  :/